# systemd: who setup lo interface without ifupdown?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

What component / package is responsible bringing up `lo` network interface with systemd as PID1 without `ifupdown` package?

In Debian, we have quite a lot of component to manage network, `ifupdown`, `network-manager`, `systemd-networkd`.  Now, we can, and I did, remove the `ifupdown` package, which means that `/etc/network/interface` is not referenced by `ifup` during the boot up process.

I've also removed all `ifconfig` entry from NetworkManager's config file, `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, and `nmcli dev` shows that `lo` is unmanged.

```
$ nmcli dev
  :
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

`networkctl` also shows that `lo` is unmanaged:

```
$ networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  :
```

But still, `lo` seems to be up (`LOWER_UP` at least)

```
$ ip li
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

And ssh to localhost works.

So, my question is, who's bringing the `lo` interface up?

Note that my intention isn't disabling `lo` interface, but rather knowing who is responsible and when and how it does.

Comment: I _think_ [loopback](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/net/loopback.c?id=28a33cbc24e4256c143dce96c7d93bf423229f92#l184) is implemented by the kernel as a pseudo-driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loopback interface is set up in early boot (before e.g. any network servers are run).  It seems there was no significant variation between distributions.  Current Debian [ifupdown](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/ifupdown/+changelog) would bring up `lo` even without configuration in /etc/network/interfaces.  Technically it was possible to change the configuration of `lo` - and it would still be possible to reconfigure e.g. using ifupdown (maybe even systemd-networkd?).

The early setup part of systemd is probably harder to understand.  It's the code of a single program (written in C :), the setup calls are mixed in with more program-specific initialization, and it doesn't seem to be specifically documented.  However the manual page for the systemd binary does mention the loopback interface as one example of the built-in setup tasks:

> Systemd contains native implementations of various tasks that need to
>          be executed as part of the boot process. For example, it sets the
>          hostname or configures the loopback network device. It also sets up and
>          mounts various API file systems, such as /sys or /proc.
>
> For more information about the concepts and ideas behind systemd,
>    please refer to the Original Design Document[2].

Google knows

https://www.google.com/search?q=systemd%20loopback

where the code is - result 1: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/loopback-setup.c

It also shows you developer blog posts mentioning this.  This blog post does not answer your question any more specifically than to confirm that systemd is responsible.  For example, it also mentions tmpfiles, without mentioning that systemd-tmpfiles is a distinct binary and service unit from PID 1.  To be clear, the loopback interface is set up by PID 1, which can be seen in the code.

Result 3:

systemd for Administrators, Part VIII
[0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-new-configuration-files](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-new-configuration-files) - Cached - Similar
20 Apr 2011 ... Another episode of my ongoing series on systemd for Administrators: ... Setting the host name; Configuring the **loopback** network device

> Our little Project Zero Shell[1] has been a full success. We currently cover pretty much everything most desktop and embedded distributions should need, plus a big part of the server needs:
>
> - Checking and mounting of all file systems
> - Updating and enabling quota on all file systems
> - Setting the host name
> - **Configuring the loopback network device**
> - Loading the SELinux policy and relabelling /run and /dev as necessary on boot
> - Registering additional binary formats in the kernel, such as Java, Mono and WINE binaries
> - Setting the system locale
> - Setting up the console font and keyboard map
> - Creating, removing and cleaning up of temporary and volatile files and directories
> - Applying mount options from /etc/fstab to pre-mounted API VFS
> - Applying sysctl kernel settings
> - Collecting and replaying readahead information
> - Updating utmp boot and shutdown records
> - Loading and saving the random seed
> - Statically loading specific kernel modules
> - Setting up encrypted hard disks and partitions
> - Spawning automatic gettys on serial kernel consoles
> - Maintenance of Plymouth
> - Machine ID maintenance
> - Setting of the UTC distance for the system clock

Comment: Thanks!  I was grepping the systemd source file with "lo" but not "loopback" ;-P  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v232/src/core/main.c#L1735 is the call site in main() of systemd v232.

Comment: @YasushiShoji :D.  I could have _sworn_ the question said "loopback"!  I probably rephrased it because I expected "loopback" would google better.  I found the callsite as well, it just looks a bit messy to my eyes.